# Programmatically create a keyboard shortcut to "Align Center" a Text Cell without losing cursor position

Tags: front-end, customization, text, keyboard

I'm attempting to create a keyboard shortcut to center the contents of a text cell exactly as clicking "Align Center" accomplishes in the Format Menu.  As far as I can tell, there is no frontendtoken for "Align Center". This surprised me.

The problem seems to be that I can’t find a way to grab the entire cell while retaining the current cursor position.  Of course I can create code that will select the current cell and then I change text centering option to center, but then I lose the current cursor position.

The menu item, “align center” can do it so it seems like there must be way I can do it programmatically but can’t figure it out.

Any help?

Comment: Why can't you just add a short cut to the menu item? Something like: `MenuItem["Align Center", TextAlignment -> Center, 
 Scope -> SelectionCell, 
 MenuKey["c", Modifiers -> {"Command", "Option"}]]`?

Comment: I didn’t think about that.  I’ll try and get back to you!  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I don't understand your comment, is there a typo? Note that the "Align Center" menu item already exists, so you would just be adding a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: Carl Woll -My apologies.  Your method above does achieve the desired end result. However, I would still like to create my own new menu item that has the same functionality as the existing one and then create a shortcut for it.  I see that you added a comment below. I will check that out to see if that works.

Comment: It seems like the only way to center the cell (without using the preinstalled "align center" menu item) is to select the whole cell.  But I lose my cursor position when I do this. That is a problem for me.  It would solve some related questions I've had over the years.  There is comment below that it may be able to be done with Developer`CellInformation[].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key option is `Scope -> SelectionCell`. So, you can either modify the menu item in MenuSetup.tr to:

```
MenuItem[
    "Align Center",
    TextAlignment -> Center,
    Scope -> SelectionCell,
    MenuKey["c", Modifiers -> {"Command", "Option"}]
]
```

or you can add a `KeyEvent` to KeyEventTranslations.tr:

```
Item[
    KeyEvent["c", Modifiers->{Command, Option}],
    TextAlignment->Center,
    Scope->SelectionCell
]
```

In both cases, I would add a modified version of the file to the appropriate place in [`$UserBaseDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$UserBaseDirectory).

Comment: Interesting!  I've never heard of the Scope->SelectionCell option.  I can't find much documentation on it.  I'm not sure what that option is doing exactly and Im not sure what other choices there are beside SelectionCell.  Do you know?  I will confirm your code works tonight or tomorrow.  Thanks for working on this.

Comment: It works!   If you have a chance I'm curious about this Scope option and what else I can try with it or a reference to where I can find more about it.  Thanks Carl.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain I believe the Scope RHS indicates where an option will be added. If you use the above shortcut, you will see that the Cell has acquired a TextAlignment->Center option.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the standard menu short-cuts.  By pressing the following keys in sequence you will navigate the menu using the keyboard to perform the text centering.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>c</kbd>

In general, once you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> the items in the menu will have one character underlined. Press that character to select that menu item.

Update:  I think for Mac you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the menu bar from the keyboard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this Windows only? It does not seem to work on Mac.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I think for Mac you press Ctrl+F2 to enter the menu.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out all you need to do is use the token `TextAlignment->Center`. Here's a way to do this taken directly from the menu itself:

```
Style[
 "asdasdasd",
 ContextMenu ->
  Menu["Text Alignment", {LinkedItems[{MenuItem["Align Left", 
       TextAlignment -> Left, Scope -> SelectionCell], 
      MenuItem["Align at 25%", TextAlignment -> -0.5, 
       Scope -> SelectionCell], 
      MenuItem["Align Center", TextAlignment -> Center, 
       Scope -> SelectionCell], 
      MenuItem["Align at 75%", TextAlignment -> 0.5, 
       Scope -> SelectionCell], 
      MenuItem["Align Right", TextAlignment -> Right, 
       Scope -> SelectionCell], 
      MenuItem["On AlignmentMarker", TextAlignment -> AlignmentMarker,
        Scope -> SelectionCell]}]}]
 ]
```

Right/Option click on that text:

[image]

then picking center:

[image]

Just to confirm that the `MenuSetup` and `KeyEventTranslations` file are effectively operating in the same way I added this to my events file:

```
Item[KeyEvent["Up", Modifiers -> {Shift}], TextAlignment -> Center]
```

and then selected a cell bracket, pressed Shift-Up and it centered the cell.

Presumably this will work for any style option.

Comment: I still don't know what's the token/command behind that `MenuItem` and the `MenuItem` will not help in putting that in a key event procedure, will it?

Comment: @Kuba I always assumed the key events and menu system operated via the same basic code. Most key events just get a string which is a FE token, just like the menu items do. I haven't tested this, though.

Comment: I thought so, that is there is either a token+params or an explicit SetOptions expression. Does not seem the case here. This boils down to how to translate `MenuItems` from above to an expression which will work from e.g. a `Button`.

Comment: @Kuba another option of course is to use ``FrontEnd`SetOptions`` but the difficulty there is in finding the cursor cell. That's always been a pain.

Comment: @Kuba it works as a key event too

Comment: So It seems I can programmatically replicate “align center”, but I have to programmatically select the entire cell first.  This isn’t what I want as I lose the place of the cursor.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @MichaelMcCain that’s pretty tough. Getting the cell the cursor is in is non trivial.

Comment: I see.  That’s unfortunate.

Comment: Maybe someone else knows?  How do I setup a bounty for this question.  I can’t seem to find the button for it.  I read the help on it but can’t seem to figure it out.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain it’s possible to do using ``Developer`CellInformation`` and other tricks but I don’t have time to go into it more now. You should be able to set a bounty with a little hyperlink looking thing underneath the question or something like that.